# БлагословІння чи благословЕння?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова, іменники

У [Великому тлумачному словнику сучасної української мови](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/11404/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) подають 2 варіанти:

> **благословіння** -я, с. Те саме, що **благословення**.

Однак у [СУМі-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/blaghoslovennja) знаходжу тільки 1 варіант:

> **БЛАГОСЛОВЕ́ННЯ**, я, сер., заст.

Тоді чи не буде помилкою використовувати слово "благословІння", оскільки у СУМ-11 його немає?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У [Довіднику з українського слововживання. Неправильно-правильно. М. Волощак](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=25&t=67) знаходимо ( підтвердження інформації з СУМу:

> **Благословіння** [неправильно]–**благословення** [правильно]

Однак, у [Великому тлумачному словнику сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005](https://ukrainian_explanatory.academic.ru/11404/%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) ( наведеному Вами):

> **Благословіння;** -я, с.
>   Те саме, **що благословення**.

Проте за посиланням **благословення** знаходимо, що воно *застаріле*:

> **благословення**
>   -я, с., заст.
>   1) Дія за знач. благословляти, благословити 1), 2).
>   2) Згода, дозвіл, схвалення.

Отже, за логікою цього словника нормативно вживати слово **благословення**. Одностайної думки, на жаль, не знайшла.

Щодо Великого тлумачного словника сучасної української мови. - "Перун". 2005, то за інформацією з [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%81%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%97_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8):
ВТССУМ значною мірою базується на матеріалах одинадцятитомного тлумачного «Словника української мови» (1970—1980): більшість тлумачень скопійовано без змін, хоча дещо переглянуто відверто заполітизовані тлумачення й деякі неточності […] *Рекомендований Міністерством освіти і науки України*.

Щодо [Довідника з українського слововживання. Неправильно-правильно. М. Волощак](http://www.dut.edu.ua/ua/lib/1/category/1282/view/1291), то він виданий за матеріалами засобів масової інформації.